# How can I convert a given list of lists to a tree structure in Python?

Tags: python, loops, recursion, tree, iteration

So I'm basically stuck at this problem. The problem gives us a parts inventory list where each component is made up of other components (in a tree relational manner). For example the input list can be given as

```
[["A",[2,"B"],[1,"C"]],
["B",[1,"D"],[1,"E"]],
["D",20.],
["E",10.]
["C",40.]]
```

, where A is made up of 2 Bs and 1 C, similarly B is made up of 1 D and 1 E. The lists with a float as the last index simply indicate the unit price of the given basic part.

The problem is, I need to convert this structure to a tree representation which can be written as;

```
[1,"A",[2,"B",[1,"D",20.],[1,"E",10.]], [1,"C",40.]]
```

where we simply bury the children of each node as a list in a nested list structure. In order to achieve this, I tried a recursive-iterative algorithm but as we don't know how many children a node has or what the depth of the tree is, I wasn't able to do so.

Can you recommend me a solution for this problem, thanks in advance.

P.S: There is not a predefined order for the input list, its elements can be placed from bottom to top of the tree or shuffled.

Answer (score 1):

If your input structure remains same then you can try something like

```py
e = [["A",[2,"B"],[1,"C"]],
["B",[1,"D"],[1,"E"]],
["D",20.],
["E",10.],
["C",40.]]

record = {}

for i in reversed(e):
    if(len(i) == 2):
        record[i[0]] = i[1]
    else:
        # there is children
        temp = []
        for j in i[1:]:
            if(isinstance(record[j[1]], list)):
                temp.append([*j, *record[j[1]]])
            else:
                temp.append([*j, record[j[1]]])
        record[i[0]] = temp

root = e[0][0]
print([1, root, *record[root]])
```

output

```
[1, 'A', [2, 'B', [1, 'D', 20.0], [1, 'E', 10.0]], [1, 'C', 40.0]]
```

Otherwise, you can create a Tree structure and get the output.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I have one last question. If we were to implement a solution without dictionaries, would it be possible? Again thank you for your time.

Comment: Yes, create a `Node` class with properties `self.children`, `self.count`. The leaf ones will have a price. Then you do BFS recursively to create the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage the fact that lists are pointers to perform the linking in one pass by copying the children list references within the parent lists:

```
def buildTree(data):
    index = { c[0]:c for c in data }  # used to access components by their id
    root  = index.copy()              # used to retain top level component(s)

    for component in data:
        if isinstance(component[1],float): continue   # no linking on leaf items
        for i,(_,prod) in enumerate(component[1:],1): # expand children
            component[i][1:] = index[prod]            # embed child in parent
            root.pop(prod)                            # remove child from root

    return [[1,*rv] for rv in root.values()] # output root item(s)
```

output:

```
data = [["A",[2,"B"],[1,"C"]],
        ["B",[1,"D"],[1,"E"]],
        ["D",20.0],
        ["E",10.0],
        ["C",40.0]]

print(*buildTree(data))
# [1, 'A', [2, 'B', [1, 'D', 20.0], [1, 'E', 10.0]], [1, 'C', 40.0]]
```

Changing the order of the data does not change the result

```
data = [["D",20.0],
        ["E",10.0],
        ["B",[1,"D"],[1,"E"]],
        ["C",40.0],
        ["A",[2,"B"],[1,"C"]]]

print(*buildTree(data))
# [1, 'A', [2, 'B', [1, 'D', 20.0], [1, 'E', 10.0]], [1, 'C', 40.0]]
```

*Note that, if your data has multiple root items, the function will output them all. In this instance there is only one so it printed only one root*

**without dictionaries**

If you are not allowed to use dictionaries, you can still use this approach but you'll have to do a sequential search through the data to find products by their id:

```
def buildTree(data):
    roots  = data.copy() # used to retain top level component(s)
    for component in data:
        if isinstance(component[1],float): continue   # no linking on leaf items
        for i,(_,prod) in enumerate(component[1:],1): # expand children
            child = next(c for c in data if c[0]==prod) # find child with id
            component[i][1:] = child                  # embed child in parent
            roots.remove(child)                       # remove child from root
    return [[1,*rv] for rv in roots] # output root items
```